# Knife very slow for chef DK

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chefdk

I noticed that my chef commands were taking forever to execute. For example when I type knife -h it can take over a minute to run. I don't see any output when I use -VV during this wait.

What could knife possibly be doing when running the help command? Two things that jump out is that it might be iterating over something or I might have a network issue. I don't understand why the help command would use the network though.

This is for a Windows 7 machine.

Any ideas on how I could troubleshoot this?

Comment: Strace it? or try sysdig.

Comment: Windows or something else?

Comment: This is for Windows.

Comment: Have some slowness on Windows 7 too, but not around the minute mark. I've found -VV doesn't seem to work on Windows? A knife --version takes around 8 seconds. Chef: 14.1.12, real    0m8.813s, user    0m0.000s, sys     0m0.015s